# Is using `file_get_contents` on a URL with concatenated parameters secure?

Tags: php

I'm auditing some PHP code for a friend, and there are a couple of `file_get_contents` usages for GETting URLs where the user-supplied parameters are concatenated without any escaping, e.g.:

```
function getLocation($latitude='', $longitude='') {
    $geolocation = $latitude . ',' . $longitude;
    $request = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' . $geolocation . '&sensor=false';
    $file_contents = file_get_contents($request);
    $json_decode = json_decode($file_contents);
    // ...
}
```

Considering the prefix to the "filename" passed to file_get_contents is already fixed (ie, attacker can't use `file://...`), is there some way to abuse this function by passing malicious values to `latitude` and `longitude` arguments?

Comment: if there is, that's on Google to fix, responsibility delegation. you can/should perform some sanity/bound checks, ex: `. ($geolocation*1) .` to guarantee a number or harmless error string, but since the insertion is after the domain, you as a site operator don't have much to worry about, to the extent you trust Google.

Comment: `intval` or `(int)` cast guarantees to get a int. `*1` might get a float, or maybe a `NaN` or `infinity`

Answer (score 1):

There are two advantages (from a security standpoint):

1. Starting with a hard-coded URL makes sure that nothing local would be loaded (although it would be hard to take advantage of it even still depending on what happens to the data *after* it is json decoded).
2. The user input is injected into the data parameters (i.e. after the question mark).

These limits a malicious user to only modifying the request parameters sent to the google geocoding API.  Looking at the available options,  it doesn't seem like there is much damage to be done there.

It is still best practice to filter user input.  The concept here is defense-in-depth. At the moment the risk seems to be very low, but what if a later code change further modifies the way the data is used, resulting in a vulnerability?  For instance, is that `latitude` and `longitude` from the user persisted into a database later down the line?  I presume not (or you have found it if so) since you are auditing and checking these less obvious issues.  However, my point is that this function hides the fact that it is working with unsanitized input, and therefore it later changes might inadvertently introduce a vulnerability.

So yes (as you know), best practice is to sanitize/validate user input before doing anything else.  However, there does not appear to be an immediate vulnerability as a result of that oversight here.

Of course, you can always just use the fact that this endpoint is directly connected to the google maps API to spam the page constantly, resulting in either a) a larger-than-expected bill or b) DOS part of their app because google rate limits their geoip lookups.

Comment: The URI there is HTTP: a well trained and willingful attacker could end up hacking the DNS inbetween, redirecting traffic to their website, and returning arbitrary data. So I would also hard-code the `https` and I would also consider the returned data as "unsafe"